# Cannot get text in front of timeline...using z-index

Tags: css

I'm trying to add text within the timeline on this page: http://dev.greenthumbweather.com/frost_date.php?location=medford,%20or&lat=42.33&lng=-122.88&temp=36

The CSS I'm referencing in the script is: timeline_custom.css

I've tried adding position: relative and z-indexing to keep the text in front, but it's still behind the timeline.

I want to place the text within the timeline frame but have it in front.  There are some other CSS rules going on with the timeline, with files timeline-2.5.0/timeline.css, so perhaps there's some conflict, but I haven't been able to locate it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Shad

Comment: What is the text (or what is the container of the text) that you're trying to superimpose onto the timeline?

Comment: Sorry about that.  The text is "hello" and I've coded it like this: [code]<div id="mytimeline"><div id = "timeline_info">hello</div></div>

<div id="info">
<div class = "info">
Click on growing timeline to show detailed information about seasons or events.
</div>
</div>[/code]

Comment: Check source .. line no:21 "</script>"

Answer (score 0):

Your "timeline" widget seems to be hiding your "info" element after it's done loading.

I would suggest you do the following:

1) Take the "timeline_info" div out of the "timeline" div.

2) Place it right **before** the "mytimeline" div.

3) Create a container div for "timeline_info" and "mytimeline" only.

4) In your CSS:

```
#timeline_info {
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

Set "top" and "left" (or "right" and "bottom" if you prefer) depending on where you want it placed.

The order of the elements in the new container (with "timeline_info" coming first in the DOM) should automatically make it so that your text should appear "ahead" of the "mytimeline" div if and when they overlap, so you should probably get rid of the "z-index" rule.

Comment: I'm 90% there thanks to your input.  I had to use position:relative though on the timeline_info CSS.  Now the timeline is positioned about 10px too low (should be in line with map container to left when looking on desktop display but is just a bit low) but text is showing fine.  Do you know why the timeline has been displaced too low now that the text is showing?  Thanks!